# DrawingsPart not being added to the WorksheetPart. Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

Using the Open Xml SDK, I added a `DrawingsPart` to a `WorksheetPart` and then later I tried referencing the `DrawingsPart` from within the `WorksheetPart` but I receive an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
// Add a new drawings part to the worksheet
var drawingsPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();

// make a drawing DOM
var drawingRootElement = new WorksheetDrawing();

// add to the drawing DOM
...

// and then...
// associate the drawing DOM to the drawings part
drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = drawingRootElement;

// save the drawing DOM back to the drawings part
drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.Save();

// and finally...
// here is where it throws the ArgumentOutOfRangeException
// whether I supply the drawingsPart as the argument
// or the value worksheet.DrawingsPart
// it reports the same exception
// I looked up the source of OpenXmlPartContainer.GetIdOfPart
// and it looks like the DrawingsPart is not yet added to the
// PartDictionary of the WorksheetPart. I wonder why?
var relationshipIdOfDrawingsPart = drawingsPart
                            .GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart.DrawingsPart /* drawingsPart */);


// Create a new drawing element and add it to the Worksheet DOM
var drawingElement = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Drawing { Id = relationshipIdOfDrawingsPart };
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(drawingElement);
```

**Exception details:**

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred   HResult=0x80131502
>   Message=Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Source=DocumentFormat.OpenXml   StackTrace:    at
>   DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.GetIdOfPart(OpenXmlPart
>   part)    at ... my code

I looked up the source of `OpenXmlPartContainer.GetIdOfPart` (reproduced below):

```
// DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer
/// <summary>
/// Gets the relationship ID of the part.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="part">The part.</param>
/// <returns>The relationship ID of the part.</returns>
/// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">Thrown when "part" is null reference.</exception>
/// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">Thrown when the part does not exist.</exception>
public string GetIdOfPart(OpenXmlPart part)
{
    this.ThrowIfObjectDisposed();
    if (part == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("part");
    }
    if (this.PartDictionary.ContainsValue(part))
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, OpenXmlPart> current in this.PartDictionary)
        {
            if (part == current.Value)
            {
                return current.Key;
            }
        }
    }
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("part");
}
```

It looks like the `DrawingsPart` is not being added to the `PartDictionary` of the `WorksheetPart`. I wonder why?

Comment: @mjwills I believe the `worksheetPart.DrawingsPart` is populated by the first line of the code, i.e. the call to the `worksheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>()`? I unzipped the output file produced by my program and the drawings part is there in the `sheet1.xml.rels` file.

Comment: @mjwills The population of the `drawingsPart` is depicted in the third line of code in the above listing that reads: `drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = drawingRootElement;`

Comment: @mjwills It is being declared and assigned to in the same line of code.

Comment: @mjwills You're the man! You saved me a great deal of trouble. That was the only part I wasn't so clear of. I thought the presence of that method `GetIdOfPart` was weird/asymmetrical. It should have been a static method I thought. Your last comment clears that part. It searches its own tree. Thank you. Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `worksheetPart.DrawingsPart` and `drawingsPart` are the same object, this code does not make sense:

```
// and finally...
// here is where it throws the ArgumentOutOfRangeException
// whether I supply the drawingsPart as the argument
// or the value worksheet.DrawingsPart
// it reports the same exception
// I looked up the source of OpenXmlPartContainer.GetIdOfPart
// and it looks like the DrawingsPart is not yet added to the
// PartDictionary of the WorksheetPart. I wonder why?
var relationshipIdOfDrawingsPart = drawingsPart
                            .GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart.DrawingsPart /* drawingsPart */);
```

since that would only work if the object's `PartDictionary` contained a reference to **itself**.

*As such, you need to instead call `GetIdOfPart` on the parent object, not `drawingsPart` itself.*